# Adding a delay or sleep to my routine in a Delphi Multi-device application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

Using Dephi XE-7 and FMX (Multi-device application) - currenly compiling in Win32

I am using Raize Radiant Shapes and trying to create a demo where I can iterate through all the RadiantCircles and change their stroke and fill colors. I have four RadiantCircles arranged vertically on my screen. The code below works, but it goes to fast. How can I add a "delay", "sleep", "etc" after each iteration to slow it down. It seems that the AnimateColor effects my delay.

```
var
 I: integer;
 fillColor: Cardinal;


for I := 0 to ScaledLayout2.ControlsCount-1 do
 if ScaledLayout2.Controls[I] is TRadiantCircle then
 begin
   TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Stroke.Color', 4294967040, 1); //yellow
   case  TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).Tag of
    1: fillColor:= 4278190335; //Blue
    2: fillColor:= 4281519410; //Lime Green
    3: fillColor:= 4294901760; //Red
    4: fillColor:= 4293821166; //Dark Violet
   end;
   TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Fill.Color', fillColor, 1);
   TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Stroke.Color', 4278190080, 1); //black
   case TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).Tag of
    1: fillColor:= 4278190219; //Dark Blue
    2: fillColor:= 4278215680; //Dark Green
    3: fillColor:= 4287299584; //Dark Red
    4: fillColor:= 4286578816; //Purple
   end;
   TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Fill.Color', fillColor, 1);
  sleep(1000);
 end;
```

I tried placing a sleep(1000) after the end of each iteration, but it does not work. I can no animation at all that i can see.  Would sleep be the current function for multi-device applications?

Comment: That doesn't look it would be the solution anywhere. I guess you are doing this in your UI thread. You cannot block your UI thread. Switch to a timer based animation method. Surely FireMonkey has animation frameworks built in that you can plug in to. It's surely a mistake to attempt to start this from scratch yourself.

Comment: Thanks David, I was looking or something such as that. TTimer is available in firemonkey, but for some reason, I wasn't able to figure out how to do it using the TTImer.

Comment: But surely FMX has animation classes that you can hook in to.

Comment: I am currently using the AnimateColor for the RadiantShape controls. Are you referring to animation class as a means of delaying thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In coments you mentioned that you have been thinking about using timer for this but couldn't figure out of how to do it.

In short move the updating code (the one inside your loop) into seperate procedure that acceprs index as parameter.
Then in timers OnTimer event you take care about increasing of that index and executing your method like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.MyAnimation(I: Integer);
begin
  if ScaledLayout2.Controls[I] is TRadiantCircle then
  begin
    TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Stroke.Color', 4294967040, 1); //yellow
    case  TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).Tag of
      1: fillColor:= 4278190335; //Blue
      2: fillColor:= 4281519410; //Lime Green
      3: fillColor:= 4294901760; //Red
      4: fillColor:= 4293821166; //Dark Violet
    end;
    TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Fill.Color', fillColor, 1);
    TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Stroke.Color', 4278190080, 1); //black
    case TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).Tag of
      1: fillColor:= 4278190219; //Dark Blue
      2: fillColor:= 4278215680; //Dark Green
      3: fillColor:= 4287299584; //Dark Red
      4: fillColor:= 4286578816; //Purple
    end;
    TRadiantCircle(ScaledLayout2.Controls[I]).AnimateColor('Fill.Color', fillColor, 1);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Check to see if we already reached end of animation
  if ComponentIndex > AnimationLength do
  begin
    //Reset component index back to 0 so we can repeat hte animation if required
    ComponentIndex  := 0;
    //Disable the timer
    Timer1.Enabled := False;
  end
  //if not continue with animation
  else
  begin
    //Execute MyAnimation for specific component defined by its index
    MyAnimation(ComponentIndex );
    //Increase the ComponentIndex by one which means that next time the Timer fires we advance with our animation
    ComponentIndex := ComponentIndex +;
end;
```

So you basically start this animation by enabling the timer and once animation reaches the end it disables the timer and sets I to 0 so it basically resets to initial position.

If you need multiple concurent animations you would need multiple timers for this so it might not be a bad idea for creating them at runtime when needed and then finaly destroying then when animation finishes.

Also you might check next link for aditional ideas of how you can contoll various animations in Delphi:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/FMXTimerAnimation_(Delphi)

EDIT: As for explanation why using Sleep doesn't work:
When you use Sleep command in your code what it does is halts execution of the thread from which it is called for specific amoint of millisecond that you specified.

So when you cal Sleep from your main thread which is used for UI updating you actually halts the UI updating for that specific time and by doins so prevents your program to update the UI to current status.

That is why it seems that your animation doesent happen but you get final result imediately.

Now in order for that to work as you want it to you would have to force your program UI to update itself before you call Sleep.

You could achieve this by calling Application.ProcessMessages but I don't recomed doing this this way as it can bring lots of other problems.